# Tricky appendices: Issues with header or ToC. Ranking the appendices as subsections

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, header-footer, appendices

I am trying to obtain a pretty appendix and ToC, however I am experiencing a number of issues and it seems that I have to choose:

If I use the traditional code:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,caption,}
  \begin{document}

\appendices
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc

      \section{Abbreviations and symbols}
\end{document}
```

I obtain an table of contents where the appendix A, B and so on, are ranked as a section:
[image: Example code 1]
If I call appendix A for `\subsection{Abbreviations and symbols}` I obtain the right "rank", however, instead of being named A and B, it is now called .1 and .2 etc...

As an alternative I have used this other code, however although I obtain a nice looking TOC, my headers is wrongfully set as the section before the Appendix (which is because of my "newcommand" I believe)...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,caption}
\begin{document}
  \appendix
\section*{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}%consider {Appendix \Alph..}
\addappheadtotoc
\subsection{Abbreviations and symbols}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is how it should look in ToC]

This last code is satisfactory when looking in ToC, but not when you look at the header...

[image: The problem with the header (should say APPENDICES)]
Any one got a solution?

Link to similar problem (which is when writing report): [Appendices' sections at subsection level in TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106362/appendices-sections-at-subsection-level-in-toc)

Thanks!

Comment: you can always use an explicit `\markright{...}` to change the header, but i agree, that's a cop-out.

Comment: With `titleps`you coulds define a sort of ‘appendix’ page style and ask to change the page style just before the `\appendix` command, even patching this command with the `etoolbox` (or `xpatch`) package.

Comment: Please complete your code to something that compiles.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the first solution and just correct the numbering of the appendix subsections in the way you do in the second version.  This results in empty descriptions in the headings in the appendix; it is not clear to me whether that is what you want or not, but it is better than a wrong heading.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,caption,appendix}

\usepackage{lipsum} %For filler text

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{headings}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test}
\subsection{Testing}
\lipsum[1-20]

\appendices
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}

\subsection{Abbreviations and symbols}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```